# Quicksorting binary array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I would like to know how many comparisons, in the worst case, does Quicksort need to sort an binary array of size `n`.
I can't find out what the worst case for this problem. `[0 1 0 1 0 1..]` ?
Cheers,
eo

Comment: the worst case is O(n2) irrelevant to the content but on average it will be O(n log n)

Comment: If you know the array consists of only 0 and 1, then don't use quicksort. A single partition pass will be good enough.

Comment: I know it's not the best way to use quicksort, but I need to know its worst case complexity on this problem

Comment: Just change your call from `std::sort` to `std::partition`. `std::partition` guarantees exactly `n` key comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly quicksort, but if you want to sort a binary array you can do it in O(n). Just count how many 1's and 0's you have then write then in the order you want.

For example, for the following array:

```
[0 1 0 1 0 1 1]
```

You can count, in O(n) that you have three 0's and four 1's. Then you just rewrite your array first with the three 0's and then with the four 1's.

Comment: but in this case you iterated through the array 2 times one for counting and one for writing

Comment: Correct, but the algorithm is O(n).

Comment: The second pass performs no key comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array that consists of a small number of unique keys is common in practice.
One would like an algorithm that adapts to O(n) time when the number of unique keys is O(1).
Which in your case there are just two unique keys.

QuickSort is O(nlogn) on average, But O(n^2) on worst case, for your case I've tested the quicksort algorithm on this array  `[ 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 ]` , the lenght of the array is `13` elements, and the algorithm takes `170` iteration to sort this array, which is `n^2`.

And this pseudo code for O(n) algorithm:

```
let n0 <- 0;
for i=0  to lenght(A)
    if A[i] == 0
        A[n0] = 0;
        ++n0

for i=n0 to lenght(A)
    A[i] = 1
```